# Dictionary append not working in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, append

Why is `append(data)` not working?

```
import Foundation

//This is working.
let tablelist:[String: String] = [
    "red1": "manu1",
    "blue1": "chelsea1",
    "yellow1": "dort1",
    "green1": "nakamura1",
    "purple1": "real1"
]

var resulttablelist = [String: String]()

resulttablelist = tablelist

resulttablelist.removeAll()

for data in tablelist {
if data.value.contains("manu1") {

    //This append(data) not working. I have an error. I need your help.
    var resulttablelist = [String: String]()
    resulttablelist.append(data)

    print(resulttablelist)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
//Error!! value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'append'
```

This sample code is working.

```
for data in tablelist {
if data.value.contains("manu1") {
    print(data)
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
(key: "red1", value: "manu1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary does not have an append method in Swift. You need to use `resulttablelist["manu1"] = data` instead of `resulttablelist.append(data)`

Comment: Thanks guys. Your answer perfect. I am going to study more and try my best.

Answer (score 0):

try resulttablelist[Key] = Value

resulttablelist is a dictionary so it needs to be have a key value pair

where the key and value are both strings

edit: in your case it would be

```
  resulttablelist[data.key] = data.value
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Your answer perfect. I am going to study more and try my best.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a key and it's value, you should replace your append by 
`resulttablelist[data.key] = data.value`
And be careful with the line `var resulttablelist = [String: String]()` in the for in as you reset your array each time.

Comment: Thanks guys. Your answer perfect. I am going to study more and try my best.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this method:

```
YOUR_DICTIONARY.updateValue(_ value: Dictionary.Value, forKey key: Dictionary.Key)
```

Source:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue

Answer (score -1):

Put this var resulttablelist = String: String out of brakets

```
  import Foundation

    //This is working.
    let tablelist:[String: String] = [
                                      "red1": "manu1",
                                      "blue1": "chelsea1",
                                      "yellow1": "dort1",
                                      "green1": "nakamura1",
                                      "purple1": "real1"
                                      ]

    var resulttablelist = [String: String]()

    resulttablelist = tablelist

    resulttablelist.removeAll()

    var newresulttablelist = [String: String]()
    for data in tablelist {
        if data.value.contains("manu1") {

            newresulttablelist.append(data)

            print(newresulttablelist)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Your answer perfect. I am going to study more and try my best.